# Get Listing Of All Photos (Even pictures stored online) - Picasa image database Uri?

Tags: android, picasa, android-contentresolver, mediastore

Anyone know how to get a listing of all images that show up in the Android Gallery?

This query is only gets pictures taken locally on the phone.  Does anyone know the URI where the Picasa image database is stored??  Appreciate the help.

```
private void getListOfAllPictures()
{
    final String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media._ID, MediaColumns.DATA, MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME, Images.Media.ORIENTATION, Images.Media.LATITUDE, Images.Media.LONGITUDE };

    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
            filePathColumn, null, null, null);

    Vector<ImageDescriptor> imageDescriptors = new Vector<ImageDescriptor>();
    if(cursor != null)
    {
        cursor.moveToFirst();

        int IMG_ID_INDEX        = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media._ID);
        int DATA_INDEX          = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaColumns.DATA);
        int LATITUDE_INDEX      = cursor.getColumnIndex(Images.Media.LATITUDE);
        int LONGITUDE_INDEX     = cursor.getColumnIndex(Images.Media.LONGITUDE);
        int ORIENTATION_INDEX   = cursor.getColumnIndex(Images.Media.ORIENTATION);

        while(!cursor.isAfterLast())
        {
            //Blah Blah

            cursor.moveToNext();
        }
    }
    cursor.close();
    Log.v(TAG, "Found " + imageDescriptors.size() + " images.");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

ok its my code and it work for me it give all images which i can see in Android Gallery
just call this function from this line

```
  getallimages(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory());
```

and my function is below

```
private void getallimages(File dir)
    {

                String[] STAR = { "*" };

        final String orderBy = MediaStore.Images.Media.DEFAULT_SORT_ORDER;
        Cursor imagecursor = cntx.getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, STAR, null, null, orderBy);
        int image_column_index = imagecursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
        int count = imagecursor.getCount();
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            imagecursor.moveToPosition(i);
            int id = imagecursor.getInt(image_column_index);
            ImageItem imageItem = new ImageItem();

                imageItem.filePath = imagecursor.getString(imagecursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA));

                    imageItem.id = id;
                    imageItem.selection = false; //newly added item will be selected by default
                    controller.images.add(imageItem);   


 }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  But this doesn't work, it still only returns local images.  The images located online (picasa) are not being returned by the query

Comment: Thanks, my code also did this.  Was specifically looking for *online* Picasa pictures...I think this needs to be manually implemented using the Picasa API Google provides.